# How can I select the closest value in SQL,but only when that value is bigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, closest

I have the following table with some data:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+-------+ 
| id | length | weight | height | width |
+----+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1  | 10     | 45     | 80     | 20    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| 2  | 30     | 55     | 70     | 32    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| 3  | 30     | 65     | 80     | 21    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

I want to select the closest value to the length and height, but it has to be bigger than the value that I indicate. For example, if I write in the input:

```
1)Length=20 and height=68 it should return id=2
2)Length=20 and height=71 it should return id=3
```

I´ve tried with this (for example for the first case), but I get a syntax error:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM `elements` ORDER BY length-20 AND height-68
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `WHERE` clause to only return rows with "bigger" values.

```
SELECT *
FROM `elements`
where Length >= 20 and height >= 68
ORDER BY length + height
LIMIT 1
```

The `ORDER BY` will sort rows with smaller length + height first. Use `LIMIT 1` to pick the smallest one.

Comment: This is not working for me. I´m using phpMyAdmin and I get a syntax error and I don´t know why. Also, when I execute the statement this is added at the end: 'LIMIT 0, 25'. If I don´t write 'Top 1' it works but it returns a lot of rows, but when I write 'Top 1' I get that syntax error

Comment: Now MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `where`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) e.*
FROM elements e
WHERE length >= 20 AND height >= 20
ORDER BY length * height;
```

You don't specify what "closeness" means.  This uses the overall area.

Comment: This is not working for me. I´m using phpMyAdmin and I get a syntax error and I don´t know why. Also, when I execute the statement this is added at the end: 'LIMIT 0, 25'. If I don´t write 'Top 1' it works but it returns a lot of rows, but when I write 'Top 1' I get that syntax error

Answer (score 0):

A version when the `length` is twice important as `height`, for example.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM myTable
where Length >= 20 and height >= 68
ORDER BY 2*(length-20) + (height-68)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know why, but 'TOP 1' is not working for me. I finally solve the problem like this

```
SELECT * FROM `elements`
WHERE Length >= 20 and height >= 68
ORDER BY length + height 
LIMIT 1
```